# How can I pass my filtered queryset from listview to another view that uses PDFTemplateView for printing?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to print using wkhtmltopdf with a queryset from a django-filters filtered listview.

I can't use post because my list.html template is not a form.

```
filter_set = []

class IssueListView(TemplateListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssueListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        global filter_set
        filter_set = []
        for issue in context['object_list']:
            filter_set.append(issue.pk)
        return context

class IssuePDF(ReportTemplateView):
    report_title = 'Complaints Register'
    model = Issue
    object_list = Issue.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssuePDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['report_title'] = self.report_title
        context['object_list'] = self.model.objects.all()
        global filter_set
        context['object_list'] = Issue.objects.filter(pk__in=filter_set)
        return context
```

This works because I am currently using a global variable but the queryset changes everytime I print in the Production Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve that.

**One** is to store in session, like this:

```
class IssueListView(TemplateListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssueListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.request.session['filter_set'] = list(context['object_list'].values_list('pk', flat=True))  # This can be done get_queryset method as well
        return context
```

And use it in `IssuePDF`:

```
class IssuePDF(ReportTemplateView):
    report_title = 'Complaints Register'
    model = Issue
    object_list = Issue.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssuePDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['report_title'] = self.report_title
        filter_set = self.request.session.get('filter_set', None)
        if filter_set:
            context['object_list'] = Issue.objects.filter(pk__in=filter_set)
        return context
```

**Another** way of achieving it is to pass the context as get parameter. Like this:

```
 class IssueListView(TemplateListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssueListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter_set'] = list(context['object_list'].values_list('pk', flat=True)) 
        return context
```

In template, update the print button/link like this:

```
<a href="{url 'app_name:print_view_url_name'}?filter_set={{ filter_set }}"
```

And use it in `IssuePDF` like this:

```
class IssuePDF(ReportTemplateView):
    report_title = 'Complaints Register'
    model = Issue
    object_list = Issue.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssuePDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['report_title'] = self.report_title
        filter_set = self.request.GET.get('filter_set', None)
        if filter_set:
            context['object_list'] = Issue.objects.filter(pk__in=filter_set)
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my guess is that the second solution is safer, right?

Comment: You can use either of them. both of them are safe.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot, been trying to fix this for the past 3 days. I thought using sessions were unsafe.